# Can this be solved in O(n) time (leetcode - 561. Array Partition)?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, greedy

Can this question be solved in O(n) time? ([leetcode - 561. Array Partition](https://leetcode.com/problems/array-partition/description/))

> Given an integer array nums of 2n integers, group these integers into n pairs (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn) such that the sum of min(ai, bi) for all i is maximized. Return the maximized sum.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: nums = [1,4,3,2]
>
> Output: 4
>
> Explanation: All possible pairings (ignoring the ordering of elements) are:
>
> - (1, 4), (2, 3) -> min(1, 4) + min(2, 3) = 1 + 2 = 3
> - (1, 3), (2, 4) -> min(1, 3) + min(2, 4) = 1 + 2 = 3
> - (1, 2), (3, 4) -> min(1, 2) + min(3, 4) = 1 + 3 = 4
>   So the maximum possible sum is 4.
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: nums = [6,2,6,5,1,2]
>
> Output: 9
>
> Explanation: The optimal pairing is (2, 1), (2, 5), (6, 6). min(2, 1) + min(2, 5) + min(6, 6) = 1 + 2 + 6 = 9.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - 1 <= n <= 104
> - nums.length == 2 * n
> - -104 <= nums[i] <= 104

This is my solution so far with O(nlog(n)) time:

```
class Solution:
    def arrayPairSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        nums.sort()
        ans = 0
        for i in range(0,len(nums),2):
            ans+=nums[i]
        return ans
```

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

Comment: Counting sort is O(n). You can use an array of length 209 to keep the counts. Add 104 to each number so they're all positive and can be used as indices into the array.

Comment: @Todd those 104s were probably supposed to be 10⁴

Comment: You may be right. -10,000 to 10,000 is still a small enough range to use a fixed size array for counts. Or a dict can be used. Try both and compare the timings.

Comment: Yes, but as the maximum input size is of the same order, speaking of *complexity* becomes irrelevant then.

Comment: Python often isn't a good platform to test out the differences in time efficiency between algorithms. Sorting is O(n*log(n)), but will likely be faster than counting sort only because the built-in sort algorithm is executed as native code, while a hand-scripted counting sort would be executed as interpreted bytecode. C/C++/Rust/Java are better for getting a feel for algorithms and time complexity.

Comment: Also note that the wall-time difference between O(n) and O(n log n) can be very small until n grows huge. Be careful in how you time things, because, for example, array allocation & reading in the input can easily take longer than the actual algorithm.

Comment: @Todd This is Python, no need for positive indices.

Comment: @code_omelette What about the posts on LeetCode about O(n) solutions? Are you not satisfied with them?

Comment: Ah yes.. good point @KellyBundy. Negative indices will index from the end toward the front.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best we can do here is O(sorting time) which is O(n log n) unless there's something special about your input.

1. Sort the array.
2. Pair adjacent elements.
3. Return the sum of the mins of each pair == sum of vals at even indices.

Comment: You can build a sorting algorithm as follows. Divide into pairings. Sort the maximum elements. Insert the minimums after the maximums. If this problem can be solved in `O(n)`, that sort turns into a `O(n)` sort. Therefore it is impossible to solve this problem in `O(n)` with a comparison based algorithm.

Comment: @btilly How would you sort the maximum elements? And how would solving this problem, which is to merely return the maximized sum, be useful for general sorting? What would you do with the sum?

Comment: @KellyBundy You would sort the maximum elements recursively. Returning the sum would not help you - you'd need to actually know what the maximal elements are. It is hard for me to imagine how to find the sum of the elements without finding the elements, but you're right that this is a flaw in my thinking.

Comment: @btilly Ah, and with "Divide into pairings" you mean in the the (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn) way of the question, i.e., such that the sum of minima is maximized? I originally thought you just mean divide (split) the input list after every second element. Ok, but then why insert the minimums *after* the maximums? Shouldn't each minimum be inserted *before* the maximum it was paired with?

Comment: The labels to the question have "algorithms" and "time-complexity". For which O(n*log(n)) sorting approaches aren't optimum. Again, Python is not a good language to use to compare the time complexity with the actual speed of a solution. The built-in sort algorihm is native code which will be faster only because an O(n) approach involves executing bytecode generated from python script.

Comment: @Todd It's at LeetCode, LeetCode has NumPy, and NumPy has radix sort ... Might be faster.

Comment: @btilly *"It is hard for me to imagine how to find the sum of the elements without finding the elements"* - Hard for me, too. Although if I understand your reduction correctly, you're assuming more than just "finding the elements", namely "finding the pairs". Maybe there's an O(n) way that just gives the n elements that go into the sum, without giving the pairs, so not enough for your reduction.

Comment: If NumPy had that (radix sort), it would be a great option to try. But I don't see that it does have that option: [numpy sort doc link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html).

Comment: @Todd Let your browser search for "radix" on that page.

Comment: @KellyBundy my bad. you are correct. np has that as one of the algos it chooses from when sorting.

Comment: @Dave Your answer btw rather seems like it should at most be a comment, given that your solution is the same as theirs so you're basically just saying *"I think we can't do better than what you're already doing, unless there's something special about your input"*.